# Xcode 7: Clang: error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, clang

I have added AppLovin to my app. I am using Xcode 7 and have everything added fine and Xcode recognizes the AppLovin code in my viewcontroller.m file. I followed the steps listed here: https://www.applovin.com/integration#iosIntegration

However, when I run my app, I get the following error:

ld: library not found for -lAppLovinSdk
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What I have tried:
(1) Deleting and re-adding libAppLovinSDK.a
(2) Deleting derived data and cleaning the project
(3) Doubled checked to see if "AppLovinSdk.a" existed in "Target -> Build Phases -> Link With Libraries"
(4) Checked to make sure libAppLovinSDK.a is in my main project folder
(5) Added "AppLovinSdk" to "Library Search Paths" under Build Settings

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cocoapods, make sure that your Project and Pods Architecture settings matches(Build Settings -> Architectures).

Usually it's **Build Active Architecture Only** part.

Comment: I am not using Cocoa pods